# Pessimistic Locking in Spring Data JDBC

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc, pessimistic-locking

In my SeatDAO I declare a `findAll` method with derived query. The DAO looks like this:

```
public interface SeatDAO extends CrudRepository<SeatDTO, Integer> {

    @Lock(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
    Collection<SeatDTO> findAll();

}
```

When I now start the spring boot application along the PostgreSQL database, it gives me these errors:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'seatDAO' defined in demo.adapters.database.SeatDAO defined in @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on JdbcRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJdbcRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Collection demo.adapters.database.SeatDAO.findAll(); Reason: No property 'findAll' found for type 'SeatDTO'

Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Collection demo.adapters.database.SeatDAO.findAll(); Reason: No property 'findAll' found for type 'SeatDTO'

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'findAll' found for type 'SeatDTO'
```

When I leave out pessimistic locking on `findAll` by dropping `@Lock`, the application runs without any problems.

What is the problem here and how can I solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will it work if you change the names of the method ? From `findAll()` to `findAllLock()` for example

Comment: It does not work. I assume locking can not be derived.

Comment: If you move annotation on method that use `findAll` it should work I think.

Comment: The service method? But this would break my onion architecture.

Comment: But I could annotate the implementation that uses this interface.

Comment: Yes, let's try it.

Comment: The documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/relational/reference/jdbc/transactions.html) does not say anything about annotating methods outside of the DAO. So I think I will not try this. But I think I found the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The core issue lies in the `@Lock(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ)` annotation being incorrectly applied to the `findAll()` method.
Spring Data JPA's @Lock annotation is intended for locking individual entity instances, not for locking entire query results.
The framework is attempting to interpret `findAll()` as a property of the **SeatDTO entity**, leading to the

> "No property 'findAll' found" error.

**Remove the @Lock annotation from the findAll() method:**

```
public interface SeatDAO extends CrudRepository<SeatDTO, Integer> {

    Collection<SeatDTO> findAll();

}
```

Alternatives for Pessimistic Locking:

**Lock individual entities within a transaction:**

Java - Inside a transactional context

```
for (SeatDTO seat : seatDAO.findAll()) {
    // Lock each seat individually
     transactionManager.lock(seat, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ);
    // Perform operations on the locked seat
}
```

Comment: I am using Spring Data JDBC with Spring Data's @Lock annotation from `org.springframework.data.relational.repository.Lock`.

Comment: If you need to lock individual SeatDTO entities retrieved by findAll(), you can't directly combine CrudRepository methods with org.springframework.data.relational.repository.Lock. Instead, you'll have to manually lock entities after fetching them

Comment: @Transactional // Ensures database consistency
public void doSomethingWithSeats(Collection<SeatDTO> seats) {
    for (SeatDTO seat : seats) {
        // Lock the entity using appropriate relational database syntax
        lockSeat(seat.getId()); // Assuming you have a separate method to lock a seat by ID
        // Perform operations on the locked seat...
    }
}

private void lockSeat(Integer seatId) {
    // Implement database-specific locking command or query here
}

Comment: Since Spring creates a proxy of the service class, how can I access the transaction manager?

Answer (score 0):

The `findAll` method is used to load all aggregates from the database. In my case, it is not even optimal to lock this method, since it is not used to modify any aggregate. As Rajesh Mishra already stated, you usually lock single instances (irrespective of JPA or JDBC).

But if we really want lock all saved aggregates, we can lock the `findBy` methods pessimistically using `@Lock(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)`, then load all aggregates via `findAll` in the service class and load all the aggregates by `findBy`. For this, you also need to annotate the according service method with `@Transactional`.